# Is there any way we can show live tweets?

Tags: video, live-recording

Is there any way we can show live tweets ticker as we see on news channels, when projecting any presentation or live video on the screen?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about showing live tweets? As you indicated in your question, you already know that it is possible to be done.

Comment: It can be done ! But I don't know if there is any software to do so !! I want to show live tweets on presentation !! Like a widget on top of ppt not a separate page for tweets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try out OBS with it's Twitter plugin.

https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/transparent-borderless-scalable-auto-updating-tweets.12277/

Complete instructions how to set it up, in the linkage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software which can be used for single screens and video walls which is called Sedna presenter. They have widgets which lets you display tweets:

http://help.sedna-cloud.com/sedna_Presenter_Manual/help_topics/miscellaneous/widgets.php